# Why is the term "string" so often abbreviated as "sz"?

Tags: c++, c, terminology

A pattern I have noticed in many big C and C++ programs - including Microsoft Windows (REG_SZ type in Registry) and Valve's Source SDK (names of practically every string variable) - is that "sz" is used as an abbreviation for "string". Why is it "sz"? What does the "z" stand for? Where did this naming convention originate

Comment: Note that some of the code you are looking at in the Win32 API is 25-30 years old;  things have changed considerably in the meantime;  the ISO C++ Guidelines explicitly discourage using this notation, describing it as *"generally unnecessary and actively harmful in a strongly statically-typed language like C++"* (Source:  https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rl-name-type )

Comment: The z stands for zero-terminated.

Answer (score 61):

Its a variable naming convention called [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). It was common in the 90's, and notably used a lot by Microsoft in their Windows API docs. The idea is to prefix variables with hints about their type. The exact prefixes used varied, but you might see a variable containing a count called  nCount for integers, fCount for floating point values, etc.

The sz stands for 'zero (null) terminated string'. Basically a character array that ends in a null. You'll also see 'lpsz' used, 'long pointer to a string'.

If your first reaction is to say why was this needed when you can just hover over a variable in your IDE and see its type, you have to understand that such IDEs did not always exist.

A lot of people still use the general idea of Hungarian Notation these days, but rarely as rigidly as it was used in the past.

Comment: Regarding the IDE recognition, it's worth pointing out that in C, there is no data type for "zero-terminated string"; the actual data type is generally a `char` pointer. Such a pointer could also be used for a non-terminated string, or as an actual pointer to a single character while iterating. So "sz" is actually giving _additional_ information not present in the type system, which was the original intention of Hungarian Notation.

Comment: "The idea is to prefix variables with hints about their type." – More precisely, the idea is to prefix variables with *semantic information* which *isn't* captured by the type.

Comment: In C, there is no "string" type at all.  
All "strings" are represented as [char*] pointers to the first byte of the value, which is an array of bytes that simply runs until a null byte is found, which denotes the end of that "string".

Comment: And the IDE's did not have syntax coloring.  Or built-in help. Or the internet.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That was the _original_ intention, but it was misunderstood by many almost from the beginning…  (Exemplified by the difference between Apps Hungarian and Systems Hungarian, as explained on [Wikipedia](DW\ 22-12\ Revelation\ Of\ The\ Daleks\ part\ 1.mp4).)

Comment: @gidds: The worst example of Systems Hungarian I have ever seen is probably the scripting API for Bethesda games. [Behold](https://ck.uesp.net/wiki/ObjectReference_Script#Member_Functions) - every argument is Hungarian, except for a few random things that skip it for no apparent reason. The whole thing is pretty rich considering Bethesda's average script length is about 10 lines (so you can see all of the relevant declarations on one screen).

Comment: @gidds While I'm sure the Daleks had something to say about notation, I suppose you meant to link to [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

Comment: @Corrodias Well done — you have cleverly divined my intent, and my mistake!  (That's what comes of posting without checking exactly what link you're pasting, until too late to modify or repost…)  I trust my friends here will forgive me :-)

Comment: I can’t be the only one who read, “Its a variable naming convention called Hungarian Notation”, and immediately thought, “Oh, so it stands for _sztring_!”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that is such a great idea for April fool's... I'm going to sprinkle random `gyName` and `szEction` variables across my changesets. The first reviewer to comment on it will get a "never heard of Hungarian notation?" reply

Answer (score 11):

As [@GrandmasterB says in their answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/450260/108394), this is "Hungarian Notation".

The term "Hungarian" originates from Charles Simonyi, a computer programmer of Hungarian background, who worked at Xerox and later Microsoft. He conceived and popularised this particular system of name prefixing.

The `sz` prefix means a *zero-terminated string*.

In both of the two main character encoding schemes, ASCII (for PC) and EBCDIC (for mainframes), the zero value means the Null character, hence the alternative (and probably more common) term, *null-terminated string*.

Terminated strings and string arrays are common in the Windows API and in the C programming language more generally, and so there is a third common term for this, "*C-style strings*".

The main alternative to null-termination is called length-prefixing, also called "*Pascal-style strings*", because the Pascal language used this approach for its native concept of strings.

Length-prefixing is where a value is stored in memory before the string, indicating the length of the string. My understanding is that the Hungarian prefix for this type of string is `st`, although I've never myself encountered this prefix.

There are different pros and cons to each approach, but the tendency of modern languages is to employ length-prefixing of strings.

Then, in Microsoft's COM technology, you have the BSTR, which is a string that is both length-prefixed and null-terminated! The common Hungarian-style prefix for this was `bstr`.

The bottom line is that there are a lot of different approaches to encoding strings, depending on language and context, without a specific standard.

In terms of facilities to cope with such variety, languages like C are now very old, and it was not designed with a very sophisticated type system. The typing system is so basic in C that any kind of string is considered a "complex" data type cobbled together from its elements, so although C is capable of handling all kinds of string encoding, there aren't built-in types for any of them.

C was also designed in an era before modern IDEs and when source code was often printed on listing paper, so there are fewer alternatives for coping except to encode things in the text of the source code.

Under those circumstances, a system of naming prefixes is absolutely necessary to stay on top of which data types you are dealing with, if you're in an environment where one particular approach to strings cannot simply be assumed as universal.

The Windows API itself is now of a similar vintage as the C language, and Windows was originally written predominantly in x86 assembly language and in C.

And Simonyi worked at Microsoft, and therefore was in a position to influence how they coped with the programming challenges of the era - including the fact that programming at Microsoft consisted of more than just Windows and its conventions.

That is basically why the use of null-terminated strings, and the use of Hungarian Notation, is widespread there.

Comment: It has nothing to do with C or IDEs.   The notation was intended for BCPL (the predecessor to C), which lacks C's data types and does not distinguish between integers, pointers, etc.  Variables in BCPL are defined in terms of machine words, so the notation is intended to encode semantics which don't exist in the language.   Prefixes for primitive C or C++ data types have never been necessary because compilers do the job.    It's more an accident of history that this was lost in translation at Microsoft, where the notation was adopted and popularised for Win32.

Comment: @BenCottrell, the OP specifically asked about C and about Windows! I'm obviously not saying C was the first language to lack adequate types, or that Simonyi was the first to use a system of prefixes. A string is not a "primitive" in C. I'm also surprised that you say it's nothing to do with IDEs - clearly, modern language IDEs are capable of providing various information that once had to be encoded explicitly in text for the ergonomics of the programmer.

Comment: @BenCottrell You might be interested in [apps Hungarian](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/), which is about making it clear what the _value is_, not what _type it has_. For instance, if you end up adding `xwFoo + cbBar`, you may start to suspect that you've done something wrong because it doesn't usually make much sense to add a buffer size to a horizontal screen coordinate. Labeling them both as `i` for integer, of course, tells you nothing the compiler can't.

Comment: I vaguely recall something like MS office was compiled with a modified C compiler that could produce warnings based on the Hungarian notation names of the variables? I may be wrong though.

Comment: @Steve there has never been any reason to encode information known to the compiler into variable names;  the C language had existed and been popular for many years before Microsoft started to popularise this notation in C.   The lack of an IDE makes no difference, since it's a compiled language,  so humans have no need to check the types as the compiler will do that job.   It doesn't help programmers reading code.   When the notation eventually did start to appear around the Windows ecosystem, it quickly became the target of scorn and ridicule among C programmers.

Comment: @BenCottrell, in C, the question of whether the string is length-prefixed or sentinel-terminated is not known to the compiler, and anyway the more important question is not whether the compiler knows the data type but whether the programmer can easily read and distinguish the data type in context. I can easily imagine Microsoft had programmers working in circumstances where it was necessary to constantly rehearse as part of the variable names the subtle differences in data types, because occasionally I encounter such situations myself, where there's no hope of keeping track otherwise.

Comment: @BenCottrell "humans have no need to check the types as the compiler will do that job." You've either got an amazing memory, or never accidentally added two shorts into a short and watched it overflow.

Comment: This would be a good answer if it stopped about 40% of the way in.

Comment: @Steve I think we agree - as that is rather closer to my point;  Microsoft adopted the notation because the codebase was notoriously messy, and the risk of refactoring too high. (Which is why I mention its popularity being an accident of history - many Win32 developers adopted it simply because it was recommended by MS).    The way this answer mentions IDEs seems to suggest that it is somehow useful for C code when there is no IDE, yet for any capable developer reading any reasonably written C code, the types are easily inferred from context in a simple text editor without the notation.

Comment: @RonJohn I've seen the issues you describe in C++ codebases that use this notation, using 32-bit integers, covered by linters, unit tests, static code analysers and modern IDEs.     None of those things can prevent a bug like that.

Comment: @Ben There was (is?) CodeCheck, a source code analyzer by Abraxas, that was apparently able to define rules based on Hungarian notation. See page 66 in https://www.academia.edu/492095/C_and_C_Source_Code_Analysis_using_CodeCheck

Comment: @BenCottrell, I'm into the realm of speculation, but I doubt the Microsoft programmer in the 80s and 90s was dealing exclusively with well-written C code of their own coherent design, but instead an utter welter of interfaces with existing software that couldn't be altered and were already designed and compiled in a variety of ways and for a variety of hardware architectures.

Comment: @BenCottrell, I've made an edit to try and narrow the scope of certain claims, and make the logical connections between my arguments more clear.

Comment: Modern languages undeniably have a tendency to employ counted strings, though I'm not sure the length-prefixed variant is dominant among those, or over all other types of strings.

Comment: @Deduplicator, what are the alternatives? I assume there are esoteric cases without general application, but I was under the impression that C and Pascal basically cover the two main alternatives - being that the string length is either stored explicitly (Pascal), or stored latently by storing a terminating sentinel (C), each style having a different shape of efficiencies which match different contexts.

Comment: @Steve: Counted string are not always pascal strings. In C++ for example, the size is generally stored in the object, and the string-data is either in the object or dynamically allocated. The taxonomy is: (string -> (fixed-length | variable-length -> (Sentinel | Counted -> (Rope | Pascal | Separately-Stored)))) Though I'm sure there are more.

Comment: @BenCottrell: It may have been used in BCPL code at some point, but was originally invented for assembly language (for a PDP-10). See https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/access/text/2015/06/102702232-05-01-acc.pdf, starting toward the bottom of page 16.

Comment: Simonyi was involved in some projects that used BCPL while he was at Xerox (and used HN in those projects), but that was quite a while after he'd already invented HN.

Comment: I wrote C for Windows 3 over 30 years ago, on computers that had just a few MB. We didn't just have data and pointers, we had things called "handles". Each window had a handle, and here were shared blocks of global memory, that were shared via handles. To use such a block I'd ask Windows to freeze it, and was given a pointer to the data; when I unfroze it, Windows could move it, so the handle was the only long term reference. My code had handles that reference blocks that contained structs, that included handles, etc. Hungarian helped to preserve sanity.

Comment: "sz" is part of the notation adopted for published code examples and header files, not the Apps Hungarian MS used internally.  The use case is different.

Comment: @Ben: You might be thinking of [PREfast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff550532(v=vs.85)) and its successor [OACR (Office Auto Code Review)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff549184(v=vs.85)), both of which were actively using by Office, as evidenced by the latter's name. They don't verify Hungarian notation, but have additional macros that give the (PREfast-)compiler additional info about types and function contracts.